# dell inspiron extra RAM to increase performance

Tags: memory

i jut want to know if increasing the R.A.M of my laptop will guarantee a better performance.. especially smooth operation of some applications like games.

Comment: Depends are you running out of RAM right now or your cpu  is clicking high usage your question lacks details as to what you currently have and your utilization

Comment: What are your current specs? What do you use the machine for? What's your OS? How much memory usage do you typically have? Please update your question and we can attempt to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in the comments it depends on what's causing unacceptable performance. The best way to do so it so check the Task Manager (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC) when you're experiencing poor performance. The performance tab should show how much your CPU and RAM are being utilized in easy to read graphs.  If your RAM utilization is high, then an increase in RAM can help. However if your CPU utilization is high as well then it may not be enough. Hope this helps.